# Promise.all() blockes the process to continue

Tags: javascript

Promises are supposed to work asynchronous. That's the whole point of them. In my code something is happening that I don't understand.

```js
const myfunc = () => {

  console.log('Point A');

  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    //Some operation that needs time...
    setTimeout(resolve, 4000)

  });

  Promise.all([myPromise])
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    });

  console.log('Point B');

};


myfunc();
```

When I run the code I get `Point A` in console. But not `Point B`! The code waits some minutes until the process in promise is done and then prints `Point B`. So, it seems like promise is blocking the process! Why is that happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce. See snippet

Comment: @danh Can it be related to the type of operation in `Promise`?

Comment: I can't think of a circumstance where the operation would matter.

Comment: @danh it reads a large JSON file, parses it, and loopes through keys to store some value in a global object. I can see with `setTimeout` the same scenario doesn't occur. I've no idea.

Comment: Hmm. Dunno. Can you look evidence of the loop progressing?  You should see 'point A', then 'point B', then logs relating to the long process

Comment: Add a ```.then()``` to promise.all, now you can see the promise didn't block the process thread. the console.log in ```then``` print after the timeout seconds

Comment: @vicki I already tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @danh I put a `console.log` in the loop. And yes. After `Point A` it goes into loop, and then prints `Point B` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an synntax error, Promise.all() function need an array of Promise, but you put one. So it will throw following error

```
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

You should update code to

```
const myfunc = () => {

    console.log('Point A');

    Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            //Some operation that needs time...

        })
    ])
        .catch(e => { console.log(e) });

    console.log('Point B');

};


myfunc();
```

Comment: Yes that was my mistake in writing the question. Edited the question. Still no difference.

Comment: I have run your code but I saw that Point A and Point B is printed before the promise is completed. I update the promise to wait 1s and then resolve it to demonstrate the promise take 1s to process.
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //Some operation that needs time...
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });

Comment: When I add async and await to myFunc, I saw that Point A is printed then wait to 1s and Point B is printed

Comment: I know. Seems like it's a specific condition.

Comment: You must use resolve() instead of resolve

Comment: Someone edited the code and added that part. It's not about syntax actually.

Comment: Ok, after update the code, I saw that your code ran correctly. Point B is printed directly after Point A is printed ?

Comment: Please read the comments below the original post. I've provided more info about the condition. It might help.

Comment: regarding calling `resolve()` vs referencing it `resolve`, the idea is that setTimeout invokes the function passed to it *after* the timeout. We just want to hand it the function to invoke later, not invoke it when we call setTimeout.  Regarding the log evidence, @SoroushBgm, can you build an MRE so we can see the problem demonstrated here?